# Input e append em uma lista vazia

Tags: lista, while, append

Me desafiei a criar uma lista vazia de funcionários e um código para que quando o usuário rodasse poderia adicionar nomes de cada funcionario.

Código que fiz:

```py
lista = [] 
while True:
    lista.append(input('Digite o nome do funcionario: ')) 
    print(lista)
```

Gostaria de saber se tem algum código para quando o usuário adicionasse todos os funcionários tivesse uma tecla para encerrar e dar continuidade.

*PENSO EM CRIAR UM CÓDIGO COM O MENU DE OPÇÕES ONDE MOSTRARÁ TODOS OS FUNCIONÁRIOS, UMA OPÇÃO PARA ADICIONAR E UMA P/ REMOVER

Answer (score -2):

Coloca uma exceção, e informa pro usuário pressionar Ctrl + C.

```
lista = [] 
while True:
    try:
        lista.append(input('Digite o nome do funcionario: ')) 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    print(lista)
    
print("Continuando o programa")
```

Comment: O [sinal para interrupções de teclado](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGINT) pode ser desabilitado, via software ou politicas administrativas, na máquina em que o código estiver rodando. Portanto podem ocorrer casos onde a tentativa de parar um loop com a interrupção de teclado pode não funcionar.